# Excessive reads in AppEngine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm in the process of bulk-importing data into an appengine datastore that was originally in another format (my app takes care of that part).

The current stage inserts objects that end up as a pair of entities (of different Kinds).
Each entity in the pair has 4 (indexed properties) and then once they are inserted, I rewrite them again to add a 5th property (also indexed, and the only property that changes) that uses the ids.

I started running into the free quota limit as I did this, so I had inserted about 1000 of these pairs one day.  I couldn't really tell how much quota was used on just that as it wasn't the only thing I did that day.

So, the next day I tried another batch.  I got to about 500 more and noticed my quota usage behaving very oddly.

My write quota used was 0! I figured this out later, I was trying to do an XG transaction but hadn't set the appropriate option, so the writes failed and that makes sense.
What doesn't make sense is that my read usage was upwards of 30,000 operations (60+% of my daily quota)!  Each of these entities, after being written, would read from 2 others entities, so a certain amount of fanout was expected, I would expect something like 500 items * 2 entities/item * 2 reads/entity = 2000, not 30,000!

How can I track down what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on appstats.  It give a detailed view of datastore usage for each request.

Comment: I turned on appstats.  Got some interesting data.  There are some RunQuery ops that I didn't expect.  I'll have to trace through my code some.  It's possible that better use of memcache will help.

What it doesn't show is how many read/write ops per call are happening, so it's still somewhat guesswork.

Also, I wanted to check the progress of my slow import, so I went to Datastore Admin on the admin page.  The stats haven't been updated in 5 days (since April 27th).  I thought that it might be because I was out of read quota each day, but yesterday I left it at 60% and still no update.

Comment: It's pretty easy to add some logging code to identify the number of entities being returned per fetch, that'll help estimate the cost per query.  You're looking for either some unexpected fanout, duplicated reads, or queries returning more entities than you expected.  Alternatively, you can do what StackOverflow is meant for: post some code, and people can look over it to see if there's any potential problems.

Comment: the reason I haven't posted code is that the issue is showing up in code that relies very heavily on a large library I wrote and I figured that posting 10s of 1000s of lines of code was not ok :-)  I'll try to add more logging and see if I can pin it down.  If that doesn't work, I'll follow up again after seeing if I can reproduce the problem with standalone code that is reasonable for posting.